# Nested ssh session inside screen has no color

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, colors, putty, byobu

I am attempting to keep a nested ssh session inside of a byobu/screen window, which I also connect to over SSH with Putty on Windows.

However the nested SSH session has no color. Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: Lack of color]

On the left you have byobu connected to `wreckcreations` with no color. On the right you have Putty connected directly to `wreckcreations` with color. Note that normally byobu has color when working locally.

I tried messing with `$TERM`, `$PSI`, and other variables to no avail. Any idea's what would cause this?

Comment: I think screen has its own color option that has to be enabled in its config if it doesn't detect it right.

Comment: @xeno Screen already has color. Its only when SSH is up that it go to only white

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be many things.

Please provide the output of:

```
echo $TERM
echo $LS_COLORS
typeset -p LS_COLORS
alias ls
tput setaf 1 | od -c
echo "$(tput setaf 1)red$(tput sgr0)"
```

Expected results:

```
xterm (optional, see below)
no=00:... (or similar, should not be empty)
declare -x LS_COLORS="no=00:..." (ditto)
alias ls='ls --color=auto' (or similar)
0000000 033   [   3   1   m
0000005
red (in red)
```

---

My guess: `TERM` is set to something unusual, and dircolors doesn't know about it, therefore `ls` doesn't know what colors to use.

If this is the case, running the above commands inside your byobu/screen session, you would see:

```
screen (or screen-something)
(nothing)
(nothing)
0000000 033   [   3   1   m
0000005
red (in red)
```

Confirm that this is the case by running:

```
dircolors -p | grep "^TERM $TERM$"
```

I would expect it to print nothing.

The simplest fix, depending on your configuration, would be:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
echo "TERM $TERM" >> ~/.dircolors
```

Comment: Got a whole bunch of strange results in byobu from your batch of commands. But your last config finally fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Mikel, thanks `ls --color=auto` solved my issue