# SSH color show only white

Tags: ls, colors

I have been working with different distributions of Linux.

I noticed sometimes when I'm using SSH to connect to another Linux server, sometimes it has color to indicate different folders when I'm using ls command. for example a folder with 777 permission will have green color on it. 
But sometimes with another Linux server, it only show white color texts.

I prefer to have color displayed. What should I do to enable color indication?

Comment: Maybe the shell configurations on those servers don't have `ls` aliased to `ls --color=auto`?

Comment: Also check the output of `echo $TERM` on various machines, color and colorless as well.

Comment: I found an answer her. I need to edit .bashrc https://askubuntu.com/questions/517677/how-to-get-a-colored-bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colorizing your terminal and shell environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment)

Comment: Also related: [Nested `ssh` session inside `screen` has no color](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6325/80216),  [Tmux eclipsed colorized output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52144/80216),  and [Colored output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283983/80216)

Answer (score 0):

Make things colored is a part of `ANSI/VT100` color codes. As long as your terminal supports that, you can have bunch of features besides colors. I deeply encourange you to have a better understading of that:

- http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#bash_tipscolors_and_formatting_ansivt100_control_sequences
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Everything else is application depending; for example: pure `ls` does not color directories and files, but with `--color` argument - yes.